# The Pinebook Pro early access builds are no longer listed. Will they be available again soon?

Tags: download

I'm a GitHub sponsor so I used to be able to download Pinebook Pro early access builds from:

https://builds.elementary.io/downloads

But I no longer see them listed.  I have done various searches to see if I could find a reference to why they're gone but I haven't found anything.  Is Elementary still providing these builds and if so, when will they be accessible again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and the Pinebook Pro early access builds are back.  Yea!